# Recursive method for a specific sequence

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

I am trying to get the value of a sequence at a specific position (where the sequence starts at 0). The formula for this sequence is `f(n) = (2^n) - 1` where `f(0) = 0`.

The sequence goes `f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 7, f(4) = 15`, etc ...

I wrote this recursive function to find the position. However, my numbers are a bit off. Why are my numbers off?

For this result, if I put in the number `f(4)`, I get the value of what is in `f(5) -- 31`.

```
public static int getNumber(int num) {
    if(num == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (int)Math.pow(2,num) + getNumber(num-1);
    }
}
```

I understand that the problem lays within my base case. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you think you have coded here, but it is not `f(n)` as you describe.

Comment: That's why I am asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said f(0) = 0, but your code checks if `num == 0`, and if it is, returns 1.  You just need to return 0 if `num == 0`.

Although I don't think your recursion will work correctly the way you want it to, either.  2^n - 1 can be expressed as the sum of all powers of 2 *less* than n, and yours sums up the powers of two less than or equal to n.  So you should probably be taking `Math.pow(2, num - 1)` while you're at it.

Comment: I have tried that... It returns numbers that are not correct

Comment: Did you try both of these suggestions?  Your recursion doesn't actually result in the function you think you wrote, either.

Comment: Your second part (Math.pow(2, num-1) helped fix the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your instructions say `f(0)` is `0`. Also, your function isn't recsursive. I think you wanted 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 like

```
public static int getNumber(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) (Math.pow(2, num) - 1);
}
```

I tested it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("f(%d) = %d%n", i, getNumber(i));
    }
}
```

And got your expected results. Of course, you could use a bitshift instead of `Math.pow` (since it's `2`). Like,

```
public static int getNumber(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (1 << num) - 1;
}
```

And get the same results.